# Keras BFGS training using Scipy minimize

Tags: python, scipy, neural-network, keras

I would like to train a feed forward neural network implemented in Keras using BFGS. To see if it could be done, I implemented a Perceptron using `scipy.optimize.minimize`, with the code below.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense

# Dummy training examples
X = np.array([[-1,2,-3,-1],[3,2,-1,-4]]).astype('float')
Y = np.array([[2],[-1]]).astype('float')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=4))

def loss(W):
    weightsList = [np.zeros((4,1)), np.zeros(1)]
    for i in range(4):
        weightsList[0][i,0] = W[i]
    weightsList[1][0] = W[4]
    model.set_weights(weightsList)
    preds = model.predict(X)
    mse = np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(preds,Y)))/len(X[:,0])
    return mse

# Dummy first guess
V = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0]
res = minimize(loss, x0=V, method = 'BFGS', options={'disp':True})
print(res.x)
```

However, the output of this shows that the loss function does not optimize:

```
Using Theano backend.
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 960M (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN not available)
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 2.499770
         Iterations: 0
         Function evaluations: 7
         Gradient evaluations: 1
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  1.]
```

Any ideas why this didn't work? Is it because I didn't input the gradient to `minimize`, and it cannot calculate the numerical approximation in this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it because I didn't input the gradient to minimize, and it cannot calculate the numerical approximation in this case?

It's because you don't output the gradients, so scipy approximates them by numerical differentiation. That is it evaluate the function at X, then at X + epsilon, to approximate the local gradient.

But the epsilon is small enough that in the conversion to 32bit for theano, the change is completely lost. The starting guess is not in fact a minimum, scipy just thinks so since it sees no change in value in the objective function. You simply need to increase the epsilon as such:

```
V = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0]
print('Starting loss = {}'.format(loss(V)))
# set the eps option to increase the epsilon used in numerical diff
res = minimize(loss, x0=V, method = 'BFGS', options={'eps':1e-6,'disp':True})
print('Ending loss = {}'.format(loss(res.x)))
```

Which gives:

```
Using Theano backend.
Starting loss = 2.49976992001
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 1.002703
         Iterations: 19
         Function evaluations: 511
         Gradient evaluations: 73
Ending loss = 1.00270344184
```

Answer (score 0):

The output indicates that your starting value is a minimum. I am not sure what keras is/does, but if I were you, I would first plot the function you are trying to minimize along every dimension. My guess is the problem will become apparent from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

To use a Scipy optimiser with keras you need to implement a loop such that at each iteration Keras is used to compute the gradients in terms of the loss function and then the optimiser is used to update the neural network weights. I wrote a small library that does this https://github.com/pedro-r-marques/keras-opt.

The way it works is that it overrides Keras the graph that Keras uses to compute weight updates given the gradients. Instead of performing weight updates via the backend graph, the gradients are accumulated at the end of each mini-batch. At the end of a training epoch, the weights are presented to the optimizer which proposes a new global weight update.